# Running processes with "nologin" shell on Redhat

Tags: linux, redhat

I'd read on a few Tomcat guides to run Tomcat as a user with `nologin` as the shell in order to prevent this user from being able to use the shell if there was a security breach in Tomcat.

I'd tried executing a script as this user with the setuid `(-rws---r-x)` and also by using `su -s /bin/sh my_nologin_user myscript.sh` but I am finding that it is able to execute commands like `pwd` 
`ps -ef` 
`grep` .

Clearly I am misunderstanding this but I can't see what the point of using nologin as the shell is if the Tomcat startup script could be edited to perform any shell command (if hacked).

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The nologin shell prevents just that: login. Any system login service  -- various ttys, sshd, etc, will deny access because they run the `login` executable, and that fails. A nologin shell won't prevent one from running arbitrary commands through a shell once untrusted code is running under that user id.

The point of using nologin as the shell is that someone can't ssh/telnet into your system as the user in question -- as long as said services use the default configuration and run `login` on the (possibly pseudo) tty.